# Media Player shows deleted songs

Tags: media-player

I had some songs in my phone and then I deleted all the songs and I factory reset my phone but still all media players shows the songs but it can't play only the name and pictures is shown. How do I delete it?

Comment: @jatin it worked

Comment: Glad it helped :)